# How can I import new Unix commands on my OS X Terminal?

Tags: terminal, osx, macintosh

There are a number of Unix commands which do not work on my OS X Yosemite 10.10.3, Terminal Version 2.5.3.

For instance, I often use this cheatsheet of Unix commands: http://mally.stanford.edu/%7Esr/computing/basic-unix.html

Take the command `webster`, which gives the definitions of words via the Webster Dictionary. Naturally, Mac's Terminal does not recognize this command

`-bash: webster: command not found`

Is there any way to download/import all Unix commands into OS X? Or at least import certain commands like `webster`?

EDIT: It looks like the best way forward is to build my own set of Unix commands. `webster` just isn't available, outside of my fantasy Unix system on Stanford computers twenty years ago. Fellow Unix nerds, rise up! Let us achieve Unix greatness in days of yore!

Comment: Note that that collection of pages is around 20 years old (they refer to sunos 4.1 and 5.4). Programs like `nn` may be hard to find.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the closest thing to what you are looking for is [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org) (or some other package management system like [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)).  It can be used to install software(including many Unix software) easily.

Comment: I'm not sure such available ports exist. Do you have any recommendations of ports which download unique Unix commands? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`webster` is not a common command among Unix systems. It is not a part of Debian's apt repository and it is also not part of the two major packaging tools [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) and [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org). Probably it is only available on Stanford computers.

However additional commands can be installed with ease using one of the two. I would suggest using Homebrew since many packages are precompiled and save you a lot of time during install.

Here is a example for installing homebrew and one of the commands you were linking to (lynx).

```
# Install homebrew
> ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
… 

# Just search for the command you want. The package containing it, will show up
> brew search lynx
lynx

# Then install it
> brew install lynx
```

Comment: Are there similar options for MacPorts? Unfortunately, users have to choose between the two...

Comment: Yes basically the same: `port search` and `port install`.

If you can't decide hop to [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32724/what-are-pros-and-cons-for-macports-fink-and-homebrew). But beware: They introduce a third possibility ;)